# Using "ON CREATE" after/before "WITH"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to run multiple merges in one query with the constraint "ON CREATE", but I'm getting an error for the following example:

```
MATCH (n:Test) MERGE (n)-[]->(m:Test) WITH m ON CREATE MERGE (m)-[]->(k:Test) RETURN (:Test)
```

Error:

```
Invalid input 'N': expected 'r/R' or 'p/P' (line 1, column 47 (offset: 46))
"MATCH (n:Test) MERGE (n)-[]->(m:Test) WITH m ON CREATE MERGE (m)-[]->(k:Test) RETURN (:Test)"
                                               ^
```

How am I supposed to do it in case this way doesn't work?

**EDIT:**
I think there might be a way around it if I used ON CREATE to set a new property "node.p=true" in one of the available nodes and then MATCHed on this property using "WHERE node.p = true WITH ... MERGE..."
But I hope someone has a better way because I don't want to use too much memory.